# ansible unexpected exception no escaped character

Tags: python, ansible

I am fairly new to Ansible and to configuration management tools in general. I've been playing around with it for the last two days and for the life of me I can't get past typing out ansible testserver. It comes back with an error message that says Unexpected Exception: No escaped character. The full error message is:

```
mac-dgarcia:playbooks dgarcia$ ansible testserver -i hosts -m ping -vvv
Using /Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible.cfg as config file
Unexpected Exception: No escaped character
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible/bin/ansible", line 79, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli.run())
  File "/Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/adhoc.py", line 106, in run
    inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager, host_list=self.options.inventory)
  File "/Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.parser = InventoryParser(filename=host_list)
  File "/Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/ini.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._parse()
  File "/Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/ini.py", line 49, in _parse
    self._parse_base_groups()
  File "/Users/dgarcia/Documents/Playbooks/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/ini.py", line 107, in _parse_base_groups
    tokens = shlex.split(line)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 191, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No escaped character"
ValueError: No escaped character
```

Have searched everywhere I can on Google and came back with nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your inventory file?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and changing my host file to have only one line fixed the problem.

My host file looks like the following:
testserver ansible_ssh_host=128.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 \ 
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant \ 
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/bibryam/Desktop/.vagrant/machines/fabric/virtualbox/private_key